# Can we provide position data to the flight controller via DJI Onboard SDK?

Tags: dji-sdk

We will use the drone indoors, and GPS will not work. So we want to provide position data from other source to the flight controller via DJI Onboard SDK, and make the flight controller know its current position. Is there any way to do this?

I suppose we can provide such data to Dronecode drone by ATT_POS_MOCAP message described [here](https://dev.px4.io/en/ros/external_position_estimation.html). I am looking for an equivalent for DJI drone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately it is not possible to inject state information into DJI flight controllers at this time. The state estimation, state monitoring and various error checking mechanisms are deeply coupled within the flight controller, and that requires position estimation only through the pre-configured sensors (GPS, IMU and if available vision).

If you are using M100 or M210, you can use vision data (M100 needs the add-on Guidance module) to provide a position estimate to the FC. This is not possible with A3, N3 or M600/Pro.

Comment: Hi Rohit, I understand you can use the vision data or maybe some external source but the issue remains how can this be fed to the drone? I would like to do this using dji_sdk package in ROS. Thanks.